# Monkey Patching and overloading methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, overloading

I want to extend the Proc class so that its constructor can also take a hash of arguments with will be converted into methods with some meta programming construct. Something to the effect of:

```
p = Proc.new(this: 100, that: 200, yes: 1, no: 2) { |arg| arg.even? }
p.call(1) # => false
p.this # => 100
p.yes # => 1
```

I want to know the ruby way of doing something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Proc
  def initialize h; @h = h end
  def method_missing k; @h[k] end
  def respond_to_missing?; true end
end

p = Proc.new(this: 100, that: 200, yes: 1, no: 2) { |arg| arg.even? }
p.call(1) # => false
p.this # => 100
p.yes # => 1
```

Comment: I might want to use `def method_missing(k,*args); @h.fetch(k){super}; end` instead.

Comment: Always best to also implement `respond_to_missing?` when defining `method_missing`.

Answer (score 3):

You can (and probably should in this case) avoid monkey patching altogether by having your own class *behave* like a Proc by implementing `to_proc` and `call`. For example, you could start from an `OpenStruct`:

```
require 'ostruct'
class MyFunkyClass < OpenStruct
  def initialize(h, &block)
    @block = block
    super
  end

  def to_proc
    @block
  end

  def call(*args)
    @block.call(*args)
  end
end

f = MyFunkyClass.new(this: 100, that: 200, yes: 1, no: 2) { |arg| arg.even? }
f.that # => 200
f.call(42) # => true
[1,2,3,4].select(&f) # => [2, 4]
```

Comment: +1 For getting the block right and the (for me) jaw-dropping last example.

Comment: The last example works for the same reason that `&:even?` works; check `Symbol#to_proc`

Answer (score 2):

Without metaprogramming:

```
require 'ostruct'

r = OpenStruct.new(this: 100, that: 200, yes: 1, no: 2)
def r.call(n)
  n.even?
end

p r.this # 100
p r.call(1) # false
```

Edit: @Marc-André Lafortune had the same idea about Openstruct; his implementation is way better.